# Webhook doesn't run the php script, when the event occurs, yet returns no erros

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

So because of the new sca changes i need to change something on my website. I need to send an email to a customer whenever he buys a product. Because of the changes i cant do a normal post in php, and now i want to try with webhooks. I want to get the customers email in a php variable.

So whenever i get a new customer i want the php script to run. But when i test it, it doesn't run but still returns no errors to stripe. Im very new to webhooks.

tried loading different kinds of stripe codes. So require config.php vendor/autoload.php and the init file.

```
//require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php'; // Load Stripe components via Composer
 require_once('./config2.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(“sk_test_ my test key”);

$endpoint_secret = 'my secret';

$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];

$event_json = json_decode($input);
$mailen = "my mail";
$testting = $event_json['data']['object']['billing_details']['email'];
```

As seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyxa2.jpg it returns no erros when i try to send a testwebhook.

Comment: "None" simply means there is no response printed when stripe reaches the endpoint. That's okay

If you add `echo "Got the email: ".$testing;' and then try to send a test webhook do you see a response?

Comment: i tried to write the echo, no it still returns nothing :/